# AngularJS Bootstrap bind popover template

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

In my app i have button that triggers a popover. The content in the popover should be bound to the data in my scope. This works without any problem when i declare the variable in the view like this `{{test}}`. However, Angular doesn't compile the content in the popover attribute when popover is triggered.

Here is my actual code

```
<a popover='<select ng-model="revision"><option ng-repeat="old in journal.backlog" value="{{old.revision}}">Revision {{old.revision}}</option></select>' popover-placement="bottom" popover-title="Visa backlog">Show popover</a>
```

When the popover is launched, i want the popover template to be "compiled" and bound to my scope.

Right now the content in the popover attribute is rendered in the popover "as is".

Comment: please post Fiddle or Plunker to help us to detect the issue. Thanks